# QUERY syntax using cell reference more than 1

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to use a cell reference instead of static values.

```
=QUERY(Responses!B1:I, "Select * where G = '"&B:B&"'")
```

I use code like this because the data is varchar, but it's so many cell references:

`=QUERY(Responses!B1:I, "Select B where G = '"&B1&"',or G = '"&B2&"',or G = '"&B3&"',or G = '"&B4&"',or G = '"&B5&"',or G = '"&B6&"'")`

How can I make it simple - like the first query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to query a range where column G equals any value ina separate range.

User @Zolley in StackOverflow [Query with range of values for WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23279816/1330560) provides an answer for this. The answer requires a helper cell...

**Helper Cell**

- In cell C1 (or any other cell that you choose) enter this formula:
  `=TEXTJOIN("|",1,B:B)`
- if you prefer to limit the range to only those rows that contain data, you could use this formula instead.
  `=TEXTJOIN("|",1,indirect(address(1,2,4,true)&":"&address(counta(B1:B1000),2,4,true)))`

**Query**

- Enter this where you want your output:
  `=QUERY(Responses!B1:I,"Select * WHERE G matches '^.*(" & C1 & ").*$'",1)`

---

**Responses**

[image: Responses]

---

**Query**

### [image: query]

Comment: thanks man, it work i use
=QUERY(Responses!B1:I, "Select * where G matches "&"'"&join("|"B:B)&"'")

Comment: Nice simplification, but there's a typo in the join function-missing argument separator. It should read `join("|",B:B)`